# CSS styling of a line: how to get the line to move with the header above it

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using a css styling template that I have downloaded. Within a carousel there is the following code:

```
<ul class="rslides" id="slider3">
    <li>
        <div class="banner-info">
            <h2>Text</h2>
            <div class="line"> </div>
            <p class="name" style="position:relative;">Text</p>
        </div>
```

The `line` class is however nowhere to be found in the css files supplied by the template. I have searched for ".line" (no result) as well as " line" (only results specify line-height).

Is this even possible? The code works and the line `<div class="line"> </div>` shows a coloured line with specific styling.

The problem that I have with this line is that if the text above this line spans multiple rows, the text crosses over the line instead of the line moving downwards.

I tried solving it by just adding to my css the code below, but this made no difference.

```
.line {
  position:relative;
}
```

---

**Update:** Using the inspector I found out the `div` with class 'line' gets the following styling:

```
element {
  inline
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

To rephrase my question: *What styling should I add to the `div` so that it moves down when the `<h2>` line before it spans multiple rows/lines?*

Comment: `position: relative` is only necessary if you're going to be moving the element around, or if it's going to be a container for other positioned elements. relative by itself doesn't do much.

Comment: You probably have more than one file, or the CSS is embedded on the page. What does your inspector tell you? (It should tell you what file and line number the style declaration is on.)

Comment: I did a global search (there are indeed multiple css files but I searched in all of them).

Comment: You haven't indicated where/how you installed the CSS file you downloaded. Are you perhaps thinking that separate CSS files remain separate by default in the asset pipeline?

Comment: I copied all the css files in the 'assets/stylesheets' directory. The stylesheets are working without problems.

Comment: Assets are loaded from multiple places. There are also the vendor and public directories.

Comment: I understand, but I searched "globally", meaning the software I use to program searches in all files and folders (so including the directories you mentioned).

Comment: I checked the inspector and was able to browse to the line of concern. I published the result to: tinypic.com/r/23lno2/8. Is it possible from there, to determine where to look for this class in the stylesheets? How should I change it's style so that the text doesn't cross the line anymore?

Comment: looks like the styling of that is coming from a gem. identify the gem and copy the files according to the format, then you will be able to edit that.

Comment: I have added the origin of the styling to my original post. I guess my question now is with what styling I could get the div/line to move down if the `h2` line spans multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions; let's address each of those separately.

1. How can a div with class="line" be styled if there is no `.line` in the CSS?

   There are many ways that don't require `.line`: using `.banner-info > h2 + div` or `.banner-info > div:first-of-type` or `.banner-info :nth-child(2)`for a selector, etc.

   As was stated in the comments, you can find this out by using your browser's dev tools. All browsers have ways to show you which styles for a certain element come from which source.
2. When the h2 is larger than one line of text, the div appears inside the h2 rather than below it.

   If this isn't caused by the div having a `position` style (which you already tried), it may be that the h2 has a fixed height set in the CSS. Try to find this and remove the `height` property, or override the height later in your custom CSS with `height:auto`.